# Using JavaScript and PHP to create a Button

Tags: javascript, php, html, wamp

I am trying to create a button after a list. It needs to check to see that a selection has been made and then based off of the selection produce a new list.

```
`Select a Horse Type: ";
    echo $table_header_horse_type;
    $array_of_horses = ["horse_type" => "Horse Type"];
    $user_horse_type_options = array( 
        "mh_maintenance" => "Mature Horse, Maintenance", 
        "mh_mare_late_gest" => "Mare - Late Gestation", 
        "mh_mare_early_lac" => "Mare - Early Lactation", 
        "mh_mare_late_lact" => "Mare - Late Lactation", 
        "w_light" => "Working, Light", 
        "w_mod" => "Working, Moderate", 
        "w_heavy" => "Working, Intense", 
        "yh_nurse_foal" => "Nursing Foal, 3 months", 
        "yh_wean_foal" => "Weaning Foal, 6 months", 
        "yh_year_foal" => "Yearling Foal, 12 months", 
        "yh_long_year" => "Long Yearling, 18 months", 
        "yh_two_yrs" => "Two Year Old, 24 months" ); //Array for horse type - have user select one
    $selector_horse_type = '';
    foreach( $user_horse_type_options as $unique_name => $human_readable ){
        $selector_horse_type .= '' . $human_readable . '';
    }
    $selector_horse_type .= "";
    echo $selector_horse_type; //Display the list picker to page`
```

Comment: this sounds like it can/should be done with javascript.   what have you tried so far?

Comment: The issue is that I am very new to all of the following: JavaScript, PHP, and wamp. I am not sure where to start. Are there any good references or examples to help a beginner out?

Answer (score 0):

A good way is to do this with Javascript.  You would not be creating the button if the selection has been made, but you would be displaying the button after the selection was made.  A good JavaScript plugin that is highly used is Jquery UI.  You would be useing the Show() function : here is a link http://jqueryui.com/show/.  If you add your code to this question, we can help further.